# PHP Select and Separate items

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I've the following table in MySQL:

Table Name : all_items

---

```
item_no qty
1l900fu 1
1l950be 2
1l1000bk 3
1l1020rd 5
1l1200fu 7
```

I need to do two selections, in which it should output two different csv files as follows:

```
CSV file 1                                       CSV file 2
    item_no qty                                     item_no qty 
    1l900fu 1                                        1l1000bk 3
    1l950be 2                                        1l1020rd 5
                                                     1l1200fu 7
```

According to the above table, the string contains digits and letters, so I thought about doing a `strlen`, but I'm not sure how to place it inside the query statement:

```
//CSV file 1

$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_no, qty FROM all_items ORDER BY item_no Asc");

//Excuting Values from Mysql to CSV
$row = 1; // 1-based index
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $col = 0;
//Row Values
    foreach($row_data as $key=>$value) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}
```

Any idea how it might work? I want to separate the `item_no` based on `strlen`.

Sorry, I'm not that familiar with PHP. Please help!

Comment: you can use intval() to get int value of a string

Comment: What does 1000 refer to ? If it's quantity threshold, then what does `strlen` have to do with it ?

Comment: Funny, looks like somebody else just asked a similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284386/mysql-compare-two-columns

Comment: @MarcelloRomani `strlen` counts characters, so i `1l900bk` is 7 while `1l1000bk` is 8..I want to `select` items where `strlen = 8`...Does it make any sense ?

Comment: That makes sense on its own. But how does `strlen(item_no)` relate to this: "contains items less than 1000 and the other file more than 1000" ?

Comment: I eventually got it, I think. Your question was poorly worded IMHO, plus you made an example that had the misleading coincidence to show items with quantities below a threshold on the left, and items with quantities above that threshold on the right. So I assumed you wanted to divide them by quantity, not by a number embedded within their name.
My fault, after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern: 1l900fu

Two characters, followed by the number, followed by some letters.

Use `substr()` to get the string after the first two letters.

Then you'll have 900fu.

Then use a regular expression to grab only numericals up to but not including the first alpha it encounters. This leaves you with:

900.

Then use `intval()`

Create two arrays, if `intval()` is < 1000, push to the first array, else, push to the second array.

Build your output however you want from those two arrays.

or do you HAVE to do everything in MySQL for some reason?

Comment: Could do the whole thing with regex if you wanted to if you know it always starts with two characters before the number.

Comment: Your idea works. What if item_no like `12l1000bk` contains two numbers before letter. I don't think `substr` would be the right choice ?

Comment: Then the pattern you described initially has changed. In this case the only pattern I can see is: from start of string, continue until found letter, skipping it, capture all numericals until but not including alpha. You need a reliable dataset, regex and `preg_match()` to solve your problem.

Comment: How does this `separate the item_no based on strlen`? And performance would be a good reason not to use all those (expensive) string functions and regexes inside a loop, but do it all in mysql... Especially if the number of records increases, the performance difference will become very noticeable!

Comment: Because before he said he wanted columns in the left to have < 1000 and the one on the right to have > 1000 based off the numbers inside the item_no string. That's what I was led to believe prior to edit. I just assumed his `strlen()` idea was a beginners mistake.

Comment: From history: `I need to do two selections, in which it should output two different csv files that one contains items less than 1000 and the other file more than 1000.`

Comment: I'll add that based on that, I think your solution will break if the item_no is 50 or 10,000 if you base it off `strlen`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the mysql `LENGTH()` function which is the equivalent of php `strlen`. Your queries would look something like this:

csv1:

```sql
SELECT item_no, qty, LENGTH(item_no) as length 
FROM all_items 
HAVING length = 7 
ORDER BY item_no ASC
```

csv2:

```sql
SELECT item_no, qty, LENGTH(item_no) as length 
FROM all_items 
HAVING length = 8 
ORDER BY item_no ASC
```

Comment: I've tried the above code but i got the following error : `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`.

Comment: My bad, the `where`has to be `having`off course. Will correct my answer!