# Mysql Compare two columns

Tags: mysql

I've a database table with the following columns:
id_product, qty, total

I want to select all products where qty < total.
This is what I'm using right now but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_products WHERE id_product='$id' AND qty < total;
```

Comment: It was missing a single quote on 'qty' > 'total'

Comment: that'd be wrong. `'qty'` is a string with the letters `q`, `t`, and `y`. `qty` by itself is a field whose name is "qty". ditto for total. `'qty' < 'total'` is only true because `q` comes before `t` in the alphabet, not because you're comparing those fields' values. your where clause is now the equivalent of `where 1=1`, which is ALWAYS true.

Comment: Hum...that makes sense...so what's the right solution?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query as written. if it's not returning anything, then you don't have any records with the specified id whose qty's are less than than the total.

Comment: It works like I said on the comment bellow. If the qty is 0, it returns...but if it's any number higher than 5, it returns nothing.

Comment: perhaps you're using varchars for your qty/total fields, in which case qty=6 and total=50 would actually give you your symptoms. comparing numbers as strings means `6` is greater than `50` because `6 > 5 = true`.

Comment: You were right! Thanks for the light!!! The database wasn't created by me and I didn't thought about it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you looking for this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM tb_products WHERE   qty < total;
```

you dont have to look for the id_product

small [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e99a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Marc B was right:
*perhaps you're using varchars for your qty/total fields, in which case qty=6 and total=50 would actually give you your symptoms. comparing numbers as strings means 6 is greater than 50 because 6 > 5 = true.*